# relative distance and right ascention

Tags: coordinate, redshift

The redshift-distance relation is $cz=H_0d$. So if we have $z$ we can calculate $d$. But is there a way to calculate or covert or write this $d$ in terms of right ascension (RA) and declination (DEC) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. If you only know the distance to your object, that tells you absolutely nothing about where it is. That's like saying, I know the grocery store is 5 miles from my house, how can use this information to figure out exactly where it is? The answer is that you just can't, you need more information.

Comment: To add to the previous comment: In 3D space you need three coordinates to locate an object. Ra, Dec are two (position on a sphere), z (or some other radial distance measure for nearby objects) is the third. Astronomy usually tries to make do with just Ra, Dec because that's easy to measure.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you only know the distance to your object, that tells you absolutely nothing about where it is. That's like saying, I know the grocery store is 5 miles from my house, how can use this information to figure out exactly where it is? The answer is that you just can't, you need more information. – zephyr

In 3D space, you need three coordinates to locate an object. Ra, Dec are two (position on a sphere), z (or some other radial distance measure for nearby objects) is the third. Astronomy usually tries to make do with just Ra, Dec because that's easy to measure. – Alex

(comments converted to answer under cc licence)